# What does "super(Car.class);" do in a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, super, java.lang.class

I am a beginner in java. Please explain me what does "super(Car.class);" do in a constructor?

```
public class CarDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl<Long, Car> implements CarDao {

public CarDaoImpl() {
super(Car.class);
}
}
```

Comment: Which bit is confusing - what `super` means, what `Car.class` means, or why someone might be doing this?

Comment: Note: the fact that `CarDaoImpl` is a `AbstractDaoImpl<Long, Car>` can be obtained using reflection. This means having to specify it wouldn't be need for a concrete class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you posed in your question I assume the class `AbstractDaoImpl` to be something like this:

```
public class AbstractDaoImpl<S, T> {
    public AbstractDaoImpl(Class<T> clazz) {
        ...
    }
}

public class CarDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl<Long, Car> implements CarDao {
    public CarDaoImpl() {
        super(Car.class);
    }
}
```

So it requires the subclasses to give a class of `<T>` to them.

Why is this done?

You may have heard of *type erasure* in Java, meaning that all the generics information will be gone on runtime.

Passing references to the classes is a way of keeping this information also on run-time when it might be needed.

### Reflection

In this special case the type of `<T>` could be determined via reflection. But it is a matter of taste and style, if we would do this or hand the class directly, as reflection is not very straight-forward to use.

Actually handing it directly is the only *type-safe* way to do so.

Comment: The type of `AbstractDaoImpl<Long, Car>` isn't erased. i.e. you can get `Car` at rutnime, but you would need to use reflection to get it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for your comment. I added it to the post.